# Visual Studio does not include all referenced assemblies in bin folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bin

Assume that I have solution that includes two projects:

ClassLibraryA

WindowsServiceA

ClassLibraryA includes a reference to an external nuget package that we'll call COREEnum. WindowsServiceA references ClassLibraryA. When I build the solution COREEnum is included in the ClassLibraryA bin but does not make it into the WindowsServiceA bin.

This causes no shortage of problems when I push into production because the application is missing COREEnum. In real life the final bin folder contains around 50 files so it's not that easy to determine if anything is missing.

I've thought about adding some logic into my build script that copies the contents of ClassLibraryA bin to WindowsServiceA but that seems like a ham-fisted way to handle the problem.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem already?